# Flutter App Freezes when routing to a specific page

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a Flutter app that is connected to Firebase Firestore. The app has several pages and routing to them does not cause any issue except for the addresses screen.

When I try to navigate to this screen, the app freezes. I do not get any error message in the console. I cannot even hot reload or hot restart and can only stop and rerun the app.

**The following is the code for the address_list.dart file:**

```
class AddressListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddressListScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddressListScreen> createState() => _AddressListScreenState();
}
class _AddressListScreenState extends State<AddressListScreen> {

  final String? currUserId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            // const Center(child: Text("This is address list screen")),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('customers').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      if(snapshot.hasData){
                        if(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('uid') == currUserId){
                          firestoreAddresses = snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('addresses').toList();
                          return 
                          (firestoreAddresses.isEmpty) ?
                            const Center(child: Text("No addresses yet"))
                          :
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: 2.h,),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.w,),
                                child: Text("Current Address", style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(color: black, fontSize: 4.w, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 1.h,),
                
                              AddressCard(
                                onTap: (){}, 
                                isDefault: true, 
                                name: addressTiles[1].name, 
                                address: "${currentAddress.houseNum}, ${currentAddress.village}, ${currentAddress.district}, ${currentAddress.state}, ${currentAddress.pinCode}", 
                                onEditTap: (){
                                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditAddressScreen(address: addressTiles[1], addressIndex: 100, isDefault: true,)));
                                }, 
                                onDefaultTap: (){}, 
                                onRemoveTap: (){},
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 0.5.h,),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.w),
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 90.w,
                                  height: 0.5,
                                  color: grey,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 1.5.h,),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.w,),
                                child: Text("My Addresses", style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(color: black, fontSize: 4.w, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 1.h,),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 100.w,
                                height: 40.5.h,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: ListView.builder(
                                        itemCount: firestoreAddresses.length,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, index2){
                                          return AddressCard(
                                            onTap: (){}, 
                                            isDefault: firestoreAddresses[index2]['isDefault'], 
                                            name: firestoreAddresses[index2]['name'], 
                                            address: "${firestoreAddresses[index2]['houseNum']}, ${firestoreAddresses[index2]['village']}, ${firestoreAddresses[index2]['district']}, ${firestoreAddresses[index2]['state']}, ${firestoreAddresses[index2]['pinCode']}", 
                                            onEditTap: (){
                                              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditAddressScreen(address: firestoreAddresses[index2], addressIndex: index2, isDefault: firestoreAddresses[index2]['isDefault'],)));
                                            }, 
                                            onDefaultTap: (){}, 
                                            onRemoveTap: (){}
                                          );
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          );
                        }
                      }
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return const Text('Error');
                      } else {
                        return const SizedBox();
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                );
                
              }
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                CustomButton(width: 90.w, height: 15.w, color: primary, onTap: (){
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, createAddress);
                }, text: "Add Address", fontColor: white, borderColor: primary,),
                SizedBox(height: 2.h,),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

It's very confusing to me as to why this would happen for this specific screen since I am seamlessly able to fetch, update and display data from Firestore for other screens without any issue.

**Steps taken to debug:**

When I comment out the code between the `StreamBuilder`, I can successfully route to this screen without the app freezing. I can't understand what is causing the app to freeze from the code within the `StreamBuilder`.

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Hi, if the page freeze in your StreamBuilder, i think this condition `if(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('uid') == currUserId)` is not true, try to add an else statement to see if the problem is here !

Comment: 'cannot even hot reload' , maybe memory is too high. if you snapshot return like 1 million result try pagnation. or if stream somehow get called multiple times

Comment: @Remy I added an else condition but still the app would freeze.

Comment: @SayyidJ The stream returns only 2 documents. All the other screens work fine such as cart, products, orders, etc. and I am taking the same approach for those as well.

Comment: try to breakpoint, the easiest way is to print('something'), in every process in this widget. and initialize stream outside, try to map your snapshot and print the result there

Comment: the hardest part is that no error is thrown, so you can't be sure what caused it. maybe the problem comes from something else

Comment: @SayyidJ Figured out the issue. It was a rendering issue since the ListView after the StreamBuilder was placed inside a Column. When I put the StreamBuilder outside the Column, things start working. Cheers.